# Distinct SQL when many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server

3 tables sto_Product, sto_ProductXCategory and sto_Category

- sto_Product has all the product info (bvin=Primary Key)
- sto_Category has all the Categoryinfo (bvin=Primary Key)
- sto_ProductXCategory (ProductId and CategoryId are PK and FK)

currently it results in duplicate products because some products are duplicate in sto_ProductXCategory (with different CategoryId's).

this SQL statement is part of a larger stored procedure so I'm trying to keep it similar.

This is the statement I'm trying to fix

```
DECLARE @Sortorder int =6;
with product as  
(  
    select distinct p.* 
    from sto_Product p   
        inner join sto_ProductXCategory px on(p.bvin = px.productid)  
    where p.parentID = '' 
        and p.Status = 1 
        and p.siteprice >=0 
        and p.siteprice <= 2147483647 
        and ( 
                (p.manufacturerid = '8036ab2c-641e-487b-a577-76c09c5c3cc9'
                )
            ) 
),      
AllProducts AS 
    (
        SELECT   
            RowNum =       
                CASE        
                    WHEN @Sortorder = 0 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY px.SortOrder)       
                    WHEN @Sortorder  = 1 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  px.SortOrder)      
                    WHEN @Sortorder  = 2 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductName)       
                    WHEN @Sortorder  = 3 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SitePrice)       
                    WHEN @Sortorder  = 4 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SitePrice DESC)            
                    WHEN @Sortorder  = 6 
                        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductName DESC)       
                    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY px.SortOrder)      
                END,        
            p.* 
        from product p     
            inner join sto_ProductXCategory px on(p.bvin = px.productid) 
    )    
        SELECT AllProducts.RowNum,*, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllProducts) As TotalRowCount  
        FROM AllProducts 
        WHERE RowNum   BETWEEN (1) and (12 )     
    ORDER BY AllProducts.RowNum
```

---

### Sample Dataset

**sto_Product**

1. **bvin,sku,ProductName,SitePrice**
2. 0001,001,AProductName,100
3. 0002,002,BProductName,50
4. 0003,003,CProductName,75

**sto_Category**

1. **bvin,CategoryName**
2. 1000,ACategoryName
3. 2000,BCategoryName
4. 3000,CCategoryName

**sto_ProductXCategory**

1. **ProductId,CategoryId,SortOrder**
2. 0001,1000,1
3. 0001,2000,2
4. 0001,3000,3
5. 0002,2000,4
6. 0003,2000,5
7. 0003,3000,6

thanks in advance

Comment: When 6 = 0? When 0 = 1? What is this stuff?

Comment: Please give a sample data set and an expected output.

Comment: Aaron, its part of a larger stored proc. the first 0 is really a int

Comment: Stefan, added a sample dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stated that

...currently it results in duplicate products because some products are duplicate in sto_ProductXCategory (with different CategoryId's).

But you havent said what it is you want to happen.

For my purposes here, I'll assume you want only one row per product, ignoring the different values of CategoryID appearing in sto_ProductXCategory

In AllProducts you have:

```
    from product p inner join sto_ProductXCategory px on(p.bvin = px.productid)
```

this needs to be changed to filter the duplicate rows in sto_ProductXCategory that you do not want in you output dataset;

```
    from product p join (
        select productid, min(categoryid) as Category
        from sto_ProductXCategory 
        group by productid
      ) x on p.bvin = x.productid
      join sto_ProductXCategory px on p.bvin = px.Productid and x.Category = px.CategoryID
```

How's that?